# Следующий палиндром

Tags: python

Натуральное число называется палиндромом, если его запись в десятичной системе счисления одинаково читается как слева направо, так и справа налево. По данному натуральному числу N определите следующее за ним натуральное число (то есть наименьшее число, которое превосходит N), являющееся палиндромом.

Формат входного файла
Программа получает на вход одно натуральное число N, состоящее не более чем из 200 цифр.

Формат выходного файла
Программа должна вывести наименьшее натуральное число, которое больше N и является палиндромом.
Не могу сделать
вот код:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Задача решается хитрее чем простой перебор всех чисел.

Answer (score 3):

Задачу можно решить без перебора, если догадаться как выглядит следующий палиндром. Сперва обработаем особый случай из одних девяток:

> ```
>     9 ->     11
>    99 ->    101
>   999 ->   1001
>  9999 ->  10001
> 99999 -> 100001
> ```

Затем от числа отрежем его левую половину, перевернём её и сравним с самим числом. Если получилось больше, это ответ:

> ```
>   123_100 ->   123_321
> 123_8_100 -> 123_8_321
> ```

Если нет, левую часть увеличим на единицу:

> ```
>   123_400 ->   123_321 ->   124_421
> 123_8_400 -> 123_8_321 -> 123_9_321
> 123_9_400 -> 123_9_321 -> 124_0_421
> ```

Код картинками вставлять не надо. Неудобно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]